# Best way to return various results from login wcf service

Tags: wcf, exception

```
string Authenticate(string username, string password);
```

Give a simple authenticate method that takes in a username and password and returns a token if successful, I need to be able cope cope with various failure situations including - invalid credentials, locked account, awaiting verification etc.

What is the best way to go about this?

I was thinking about either of the two options below but am open to anything else:

(1) changing response to an object with an enum as well as the token. A bit worried with regard to versioning with this method though.

(2) faultcontracts for each of the failure cases. Not sure about performance here though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the FaultContract only when you want return more details/manage an exception on the client side. An exception (as you guess by the name itself) is something you couldn't foresee or rather something that happen against your will :-)
In your case you already know the login can be locked, invalid etc.  I think you should return an enumerator (or encapsulate it into an object) to provide more information about instead of raise an exception to force to use fault contract
I hope it makes sense